# how to stop refetchInterval react query (useQuries) after 3 times repeat?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-query

Here i am using react Query to fetch data. i have used in useQuries  refetchInterval for 3000 miliseconds, so every 3 seconds it's refetch data. so when i display data it's changing automatically as we refetch data. but in my case i don't want to refetch data more then 3 times, suppose, i want to use {refetchInterval : 3000} only for 3 times then it will stop refetching data.

is there any way to do this. how can i fix it for only 3 times use refetchInterval options. ecah time it will refetch after 3 seconds and onec it refetch 3 times it will automatically stop and no more reftech will work.

Please Help me to fix this and break the refetchInterval after 3 times.
ThankYou for your trying in advance!

```
  const fetchData = () => {
            const rA=  devices?.map(async (id) => {
                const info = await axios.get(`https://www.roads.com/road/api/roadControl/${id}`, myHeaders).then((res) => {
                    return res.data;
                })
                return info
                
            })
            
            return rA;
        };
    
        const { data } = useQuery("post", fetchData,
            { refetchInterval: 3000 });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work

```
const countRef = useRef(0)
const { data } = useQuery("post", () => {
  countRef.current += 1
  return fetchData()
}, { refetchInterval: () => countRef.current < 3 ? 3000 : false });
```

Comment: The answer to use `refetchInterval` as a function is correct - I just wanted to point out that the ref might be unnecessary because the function gets the `query` passed, and the query contains `query.state.dataUpdateCount`, which you can check if that greater than 3.

Comment: extending @TkDodo comment: `refetchInterval: (_data, query) => (query.state.dataUpdateCount > 3: 3000 : false)`