# Is there a way to know how many times a query is run (react-query v3)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, polling, react-query

I want to make a polling query which will stop itself after 5 tries. The stopping condition also depends on the response I receive in this case, so I wanted to use `refetchInterval` function to check for that. Is there some way to determine how many times has a query run already so I can stop it unconditionally after 5 tries. I can use state for this but I wanted to know if there is already a solution for it in react-query.

Also is a similar thing possible with mutations?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74094771/how-to-stop-refetchinterval-react-query-usequries-after-3-times-repeat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to stop refetchInterval react query (useQuries) after 3 times repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74094771/how-to-stop-refetchinterval-react-query-usequries-after-3-times-repeat)